# Angular date reference in a url not correct

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an angular app in which i have the following:

```
    <div class="col-md-5 form-inline">
        <label for="bdate">Beginning Date:</label>
        <input type="date" class="form-control" ng-model="begindate" id="bdate" placeholder="mm-dd-yyyy">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 form-inline">
        <label for="edate">End Date:</label>
        <input type="date" class="form-control" ng-model="enddate" id="edate" placeholder="mm-dd-yyyy">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <a href="report/{{begindate}}/{{enddate}}" class="btn btn-default pull-right" role="button">Export</a>
    </div>
```

When i click on the export button, the url that should be generated is not right.

```
http://localhost:8000/myapp/report/"2015-05-01T05:00:00.000Z"/"2015-05-26T05:00:00.000Z"
```

But it should be generated without the quotes. What is going wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `toISOString()` method

```
<div class="col-md-3">
    <a href="report/{{begindate.toISOString()}}/{{enddate.toISOString()}}" class="btn btn-default pull-right" role="button">Export</a>
</div>
```

You can check it using the following plunker
http://plnkr.co/edit/9HKmXBCh7Xn1QGEap3gC?p=preview

Comment: Your plunker seems to just be a "Hello World" plunker, where is the code related to this problem?

Comment: @SunilD. check it again now. It contains two URLs one of them use toISOString and other don't

Comment: Yup, thanks for doing that! I don't know why, but I'm really curious as to why this happens? I guess the answer is in the source code :) ... Also, if the OP is reading this you might want to use `ng-href` when you create dynamic URLs like this...